# How to Terminate Google cloud build job when SonarQube 7.8 quality gate check fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using below code in `cloudbuild.yaml` file. But it is giving syntax error and failing. Please suggest.

```
steps:
 
#build jar file 
- name: maven:3.6.1-jdk-8
  entrypoint : mvn
  args: ['package', '-q']
  dir: 'dataflows/generic/pubsub-sftp/src'
  id: 'build-jar'
  
#static code analysis by sonarqube
- name: maven:3.6.1-jdk-8
  entrypoint: bash
  args:
    - -c
    - |
      unset MAVEN_CONFIG \
      && echo "111.12.111.23 sonarqube.xxx.com" > /etc/hosts \
      && mvn sonar:sonar -q -Dsonar.login= **aa1234566789**\
      '-Dsonar.projectKey=abc' \
      '-Dsonar.projectName=ABC' \
      '-Dsonar.host.url=https://example.com' \
      '-Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true' \
  allow_failure: true
  dir: 'dataflows/generic/pubsub-sftp/src'
  id: 'sonarqube-analysis'
```

please suggest why syntax error coming.
we are trying to

Comment: Please edit your post to include the exact error that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

There are some syntax issues on your `cloudbuild.yaml`. Take some time to take a look at the relevant section of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config) regarding the syntax. Take special emphasis in the way you are handling the [substitutions](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) and your [secretEnv variable](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values). Notice that for [secrets you'd need to use either Cloud KMS or Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials#using_the_encrypted_variable_in_build_requests).

The following modification of your `cloudbuild.yaml` file presumes that you have followed the [relevant instructions to use Cloud KMS](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/use-encrypted-secrets-credentials#encrypt_credentials) (use it as a base to make the relevant changes needed according to your specific environment):

```
steps:
 
#build jar file 
- name: 'maven:3.6.1-jdk-8'
  entrypoint : 'mvn'
  args: ['package', '-q']
  dir: 'dataflows/generic/pubsub-sftp/src'
  id: 'build-jar'
  
#static code analysis by sonarqube
- name: 'maven:3.6.1-jdk-8'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - -c
    - |
      unset MAVEN_CONFIG \
      
      && mvn sonar:sonar -q -Dsonar.login=abc\
      '-Dsonar.projectKey=abc' \
      '-Dsonar.projectName=ABC' \
      '-Dsonar.host.url=https://sonarqube.home' \
      '-Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true' \
      'allow_failure: true'
  dir: 'dataflows/generic/pubsub-sftp/src'
  id: 'sonarqube-analysis'
  
#Move jar to artifactory
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: ['-c', 'curl -u $$ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS -X PUT "https://artifactory.build.ingka.ikea.com/artifactory/$_ARTIFACTORY_REPO/$_PACKAGE_NAME/pubsub-sftp-$BRANCH_NAME.jar" -T pipeline-bundled-0.1.jar']
  dir: 'dataflows/generic/pubsub-sftp/src/pipeline/target'  
  secretEnv: ['ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS']
#Change these fields according to your configuration
substitutions:
    _ARTIFACTORY_REPO: 'your-example-value-1'
    _PACKAGE_NAME: 'your-example-value-2'
options:
    substitution_option: 'ALLOW_LOOSE'
 #Change these fields according to your configuration
secrets:
 - kmsKeyName: projects/project-id/locations/global/keyRings/keyring-name/cryptoKeys/key-name
   secretEnv:
     ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS: 'encrypted-password'
```